# How to install node js on windows 8 operating system

Tags: node.js, angular

At first I am new to the angular js. Initially i had downloaded the nodejs in the website `https://nodejs.org/en/` after when i am installing the file at first it is showing the path and the custom setup after on clicking the install button it is showing the error:2503
The screenshot is below:
[ [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vrht.png]

**Update**

> when i follow the simple installation procedure i am getting error as `error:2503` and `error:2502`. please take a look at my image that i given above.

Comment: which version u downloded fom that site??recommended or latest?

Comment: Better way to restart the computer and try to install it again because this error happens when any other installation going on parallely.

Comment: This has nothing to do with angularjs.

Comment: @ManishSingh I had restart my system then also getting the same error

Comment: recommended @SaEChowdary

Answer (score 0):

Open windows Task manager (alt+ctrl+delete) and end windows explorer task (explorer.exe). Then on the same window click file and click new task run and type explorer.exe and also check the checkbox to run it with administrator privilege. Then try the installer again with administrator privilege (right click the nodejs.exe or nodejs.msi and run as administrator).

Comment: i tried as you said but still facing the same issue

Comment: Are you sure you run explorer.exe as administrator? also try nodejs installer as administrator (right click nodejs.exe or msi and run as administrator). I had the same problem in win8 and i installed it on this way.

Comment: `Then search for "Run" program and right click it and run as adminstrator`. can you explain this more bit. because when i type `Run` in search i am not getting run as adminstrator option

Comment: http://www.fixkb.com/2014/01/error-2503-and-2502-when-uninstalling-on-windows-8.html 
method 2.

Comment: "Open windows Task manager (alt+ctrl+delete) and end windows explorer task (explorer.exe). Then search for "Run" program and right click it and run as adminstrator. Then type explorer.exe and hit enter."can u explain these how to use